# redirect a url or domain with www

Tags: url, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a simple question about url or domain redirect. I was looking through the previous questions on how to redirect a url or domain from http to http to force using ssl.

The weird part shows up when I try to redirect none www. to www. with the domain. I tried many ways, but none worked for me. does any one have any idea why is that?? and how to resolve this issue??

here is the code for I used at .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\/main" [R=301,L]
```

another weird thing is that whenever I typed the domain on the browser without www. there is an error message, but when I insert the www. in front of the domain, it redirects with https and wwww of course.

any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rules will run into a loop. Do this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi ThinkingMonkey. Thanks a lot. I added the above full code to .htaccess, but still not working... I placed in the .htaccess in root for the domain, and there is another subdomain, which www that has .htaccess. Do I have to insert the above you twice I mean in both files?? Thanks

Comment: I just found out that if I write anything in the .htaccess for the root, it will be copied to the other one. so both carry the same rules and conditions, but as I said it didn't work. when I reload the page, it shows the link being redirect with http// and no www so it fails

Comment: @Fxdigi are you on a shared host?

Comment: @Fxdigi give an example of what is exactly happening. And what do you mean by it fails?

Comment: when I take your code to the .htaccess and save it in the root, I run my website in the browser "tyoing my domain without www" for example FF gives me this message: Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at mydomain.com.

Comment: @Fxdigi Just tested it here. Works fine. Please check your server configuration.

Comment: Thanks. I will check the server config. Thanks again

Comment: Thank you so much,ThinkingMonkey. It worked very well. I had a problem with my browsers. There was a glitch in them because of the update. Thanks again, mate.